# Broadcast reciever fired at the start of the app while setting alarm manager

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm developing an app which takes the system to silent mode at specific time of the day. I'm using alarm manager for this. 
I call the AddAlarm Activity after the registration activity. 
My problem is...The phone goes to silent mode only when I open the app but not at the scheduled time. I donno where I'm going wrong.

Here is my AddAlarms class

```
public class AddAlarms extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScheduledService.class);
        AlarmManager am1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        PendingIntent pi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1421521, intent, 0);
        am1.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi1);

        startActivity(new Intent(this, NavActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Here is my ScheduledService class

```
public class ScheduledService extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Intent silService=new Intent(context,SilentService.class);
        context.startService(silService);
    }
}
```

Here is my SilentService class

```
public class SilentService extends Service {
    private AudioManager myAudioManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (myAudioManager.getRingerMode() != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
            myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);


        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

And my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="net.notifoid.mcestraddler" >


    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon" >


        <activity
            android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.NavActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AddAlarms"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

        <service
            android:name=".silentmode.SilentService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".silentmode.ScheduledService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'll be great if somebody can help me.

Comment: inexactrepeating is exactly what it means. it is not a specific time of day

Comment: also I suggest you read the doc for `HOUR_OF_DAY`. it does not mean what you seem to think it means

Comment: When i use `am1.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi1)` doesn't it mean it will repeat everyday at time set by calender1? Please correct me if im wrong. Im new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're opening the app after 7:20AM, then the alarm will be set for 7:20AM on the same day. The alarm will immediately fire in this case.

You can avoid this by evaluating if it is already past 7:20AM and setting the alarm for the next day:

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
if(calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 7 ||
        (calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 7 && calendar1.get(Calendar.MINUTE) >= 20)){
    calendar1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
```